# Sometimes Queued Jobs getting wrong base_url in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-9

I have a Job (running with supervisor) to send a e-mail with the link to download a report.

So, the job run and process my data and after that dispatch an email, so this create a signed URL to download the .csv file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class ExportCSV extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $csv;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($fileCSV, $user,$content)
    {
       $this->fileCSV   = $fileCSV;
       $this->user      = $user;
       $this->content   = $content;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute('download-file', now()->addDay(1), ['database' => 's3', 'path' =>base64_encode($this->fileCSV)]);
        return $this->markdown('emails.export-csv',["url" => $url, "user" => $this->user, "message" => $this->content["message"]])->subject($this->content["assunto"]);
    }
}
```

But, sometimes the link is the IP from my website and sometimes is the correct domain.

Examples:

(correct)
https://example.com/download-file/s3/ZXhwb3J0cy9FeHBvcnRhw6fDo28tMTY1OTYyNDU4MS5jc3Y=?expires=1659710981&signature=362ec684c8c6e955980da089c0ed618f03b820737ef596ac48ea8ce643e26b92

(wrong)
http://192.168.0.1/download-file/s3/ZXhwb3J0cy9FeHBvcnRhw6fDo28tMTY1OTYyNDU4MS5jc3Y=?expires=1659710981&signature=362ec684c8c6e955980da089c0ed618f03b820737ef596ac48ea8ce643e26b92

I config my .env file, and cleaned all cache.
But I cant understand why sometimes the link is correct and sometimes is wrong.

Comment: probably not a correct answer so putting it in comments: but we had this issue in production and sometimes, running composer dump autoload helped.

Comment: Do you restart the queue in between deployments?

Comment: so many things could be wrong. Are you running `config:cache`? are you using a server that is always on or are you deleting servers in between deployments (so you may be missing config)?

Comment: Yes I run all commands about clean cache and config. My worker auto restart after all changes. I will try use the composer dump